# how to add new php settings not in php.ini but in separate file

Tags: php

My aim is to put my custom setting like debugger config lines in separate file which will be loaded after php.ini! Reason is a trouble with making xdebugger working after php update! Is it possible somehow keep this separately, because while updating php, it is rewriting php.ini! I tried to find answer in google, but results are out of my question range!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP configuration is set in `/etc/php/php.ini`. In `/etc/php/` directory is also `conf.d` directory which contains extra configuration.

You can create in this directory your `custom.ini` configuration which will not be affected during the update.

Remember that paths can vary depending on the operation system.